# EJB3 and UML how to create sequence diagram

Tags: uml, ejb-3.0

Hello i have problem with EJB and UML
in EJB 2 entity bean and database have cooperate each other , but EJB 3 i try EntityManager in SessionBean to excute insert/delete/update 
How can i draw sequence diagram with EJB3?

Answer (score 0):

In EJB3 you get annotations in the java code, no more need for other files.
You therefore just have to reverse you java code method into a sequence diagram.

I use Omondo for my project and get my annotations displayed as EJB3 stereotypes.

Hope this help. 
I don't know about other tool supporting sequence diagram reverse but if you look well you could find other alternative to Omondo's expensive solutions.

Comment: it mean i can ignore EntityManager? just draw session bean interactive  with Database?

Comment: Not really. You need to use annotations with a mapper such as Hibernate. Uml reverse engineering of a method within the sequence diagram will only display the existing information and add annotation graphical information.

Comment: ah ok I get your point. EJB3 modeling is really complexe and is sometimes totally outside the code and therefore java annotation. I don't use this kind of modeling because too abstract. Sorry mate !!